# nth-child doesn't work when I add a href line inside

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

Hello i have one problem with nth-child its works perfectly before i add the following code: ** inside div id "programet"

Can anyone help me ?

```
**<a href="http://www.turkishairlines.com" target="_blank"><img style="width:400px;margin-top:12px;border:5px solid #fff;" src="http://www.oranews.tv/banner/punesim2.gif" /></a>** 




<div id="programet" class="shadow"> 
            <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 24, 'order' => 'ASC', 'category' => 9 );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <div id="lajme-bllok-item-vogel">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('lajmet-thumb'); ?></a>
                    <div id="lajme-bllok-item-title-vogel"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <div id="top-news-title-linku-posht"><?php for( $i=1; $i<=4; $i++){ $prop_det_url = get_field('link'.$i); if( $prop_det_url != '' ){ ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('link_titull'.$i); ?></a></li> <?php } } ?></div></div></div>
                    <div id="social-media-vogel"><?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>




CSS 
#lajme-bllok-item-vogel:nth-child(8n+1){width:auto;height:auto;float:left;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:25px 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;}
#lajme-bllok-item-vogel:nth-child(8n+1) img{height:219px;width:390px;border-top:2px solid #F00;}
#lajme-bllok-item-vogel:nth-child(8n+1) #lajme-bllok-item-title-vogel{width:368px;height:auto;margin:-14px 1px 0 0;padding:11px;box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);font:21px/23px 'lato-bold',Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:21px;font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: you are changing the number of children in the div by adding that line of code  try 8n+2 in your CSS to see if that fixes problem - if it does then find a more permanent solution!

Comment: ID's should be unique by the way. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**8n+2 in mine CSS fixed the problem.**

Thank you @Graham Ritchie